# Can Rewards Video Ads Can be integrated in non gaming android app

Tags: android, rewardedvideoad

What I want is to ask user to view 5 video ads , based on that they will get point , 
When required point is accumalated they will be able to view next activity in and android app,.

My abs is non gaming app.

Is it allow to integrated in non gaming platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reward Videos are made to give user some extra coin, tokens, points, unlock stage. This is regarding the game. Kudos.

This is not limited to the game actually. You can use it in regular app also. Developer use it for deliver some digital good like doc, pdf, ppts. Some quiz app use it for unlocking next level/exam/paper.

Conclusion : you can surely use that in non game apps.

Link of [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/rewarded-video).